# Rhel7: telnet: no route to host

Tags: rhel, telnet

I have installed RHEL7 GA version, and installed the xinetd and telnet packages. But when I am trying to `telnet` from another host to RHEL 7 its giving this error:

```
Trying 10.235.x.x...
telnet: connect to address 10.235.x.x: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

But I am able to telnet from RHEL7 host to any other host.

```
rpm -qa|grep telnet  
telnet-server-0.17-59.el7.x86_64  
telnet-0.17-59.el7.x86_64

rpm -qa|grep xinetd  
xinetd-2.3.15-12.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: As a sidenote: don't use `telnet`. Ever. It's devilishly insecure and outdated.

Comment: Add the routes from the other host to your question. `ip route` on the other host. (You're using the private network `10.0.0.0/24` so you can display your IP addresses in full)

Comment: Confirm that the telnet xinetd service is enabled. Look at the telnet file(s) under `/etc/xinet.d`.

Comment: error messages "No route to host" suggest you don't have ip connectivity.

can you try:

     ping 10.235.X.y ?

do you have any router or networking device between the two hosts ?

Comment: i can able to ping, and also, from another host telnet work to rhel7 host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution! After **flushing iptables** (`iptables -F`), it's allowing telnet connection.

I don't know the difference between flushing iptables and stopping iptables stop but this seems to work.

Comment: iptables -f will flush if there are any other rules added & iptables stop will completely stops the service ( it allows every port communication )